# Access array elements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, object

I have an array in which the contents are pushed from json response. Now i need to check and retrieve the names of the vitals which are true without knowing vital name. Any idea about how to access the array elements to find which vital is true would be really helpful

```
var json_data = {
  "Blood Pressure": true,
  "Body Composition": true,
  "ECG": true,
  "SPO2": false,
  "Weight Scale": true,
  "temp": true
};
var hardwarelist = [];

for (var i in json_data) {
  hardwarelist.push([i, json_data[i]]);
}

var vitalflow = ["BP", "Weight", "BMC", "ECG", "Spo2", "Thermometer"];

for (var i = 0; i < vitalflow.length; i++) {
  //console.log(vitalflow[i]);
}

function hardwareavailability(hardwarelistarr, vitalflowarr) {
  var hardwarelistarray = new Array();
  hardwarelistarray = hardwarelistarr;

  var flowarray = new Array();
  flowarray = vitalflowarr;

  if (hardwarelistarray[0]) {
    window.location.href = "#/about";
  }
}
hardwareavailability(hardwarelist, vitalflow);
```

Comment: `hardwarelist.filter(e => e === true)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `filter` to get the right elements, then `map` the names out:

```js
var json_data = {
  "Blood Pressure": true,
  "Body Composition": true,
  "ECG": true,
  "SPO2": false,
  "Weight Scale": true,
  "temp": true
};
var hardwarelist = [];

for (var i in json_data) {
  hardwarelist.push([i, json_data[i]]);
}

var trueVitals = hardwarelist.filter(([, e]) => e).map(([e]) => e);
console.log(trueVitals);
```

ES5 syntax:

```js
var json_data = {
  "Blood Pressure": true,
  "Body Composition": true,
  "ECG": true,
  "SPO2": false,
  "Weight Scale": true,
  "temp": true
};
var hardwarelist = [];

for (var i in json_data) {
  hardwarelist.push([i, json_data[i]]);
}

var trueVitals = hardwarelist.filter(function(e) {
  return e[1];
}).map(function(e) {
  return e[0];
});
console.log(trueVitals);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
var json_data = {
  "Blood Pressure": true,
  "Body Composition": true,
  "ECG": true,
  "SPO2": false,
  "Weight Scale": true,
  "temp": true
};
var hardwarelist = [];
for (var i in json_data) {
  hardwarelist.push([i, json_data[i]]);
}
console.log(hardwarelist.filter(h => h[1]))
```